# Correct fashion of arguments

Tags: rcharts

My goal is to produce a shiny app containing a barchart whose parameters are read from selectInput. 
I keep getting the Error: "`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'input' not found`".
I also tried, as suggested by Ramnath : `f = as.formaula(~ input$x)` but nothing worked.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
require(rCharts)
require(shiny)
aw<- read.table("G:\\Research - LPvsTW\\Text fIles\\LpIntw.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$myChart <- renderChart2({
    f = as.formula(~ input$x)

    p1 <- nPlot(f , group = "input$y" , data = aw, type = 'multiBarChart')


    p1$addParams(dom = 'myChart')
    return(p1)
  })
})
#################################
require(rCharts)
require(shiny)
aw<- read.table("G:\\Research - LPvsTW\\Text fIles\\LpIntw.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("rCharts: Interactive Charts from R using polychart.js"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "x",
                label = "Choose X",
                choices = names(aw),
                selected = "SecQof"),
    selectInput(inputId = "y",
                label = "Group by",
                choices = names(aw),
                selected = "Gender")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput("myChart", "nvd3")
  )
))
```